# how to call an object inside a constructor

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this code inside a class,

```
public class refre
{
    final Timer timers = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    public void trig(){
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        new activityIns().execute();
                    }
                });
            }
        };       

        timers.schedule(task, 1000, 10000);
    }
}
```

and calls the `refre` class here :

```
private refre refresher = new refre();
void onStoper(){
    refresher.timers.cancel();
    super.onStop();
}
```

how can I call the "task" inside `onStoper`?

Comment: `task` is a **local** variable in the `trig()` method, you can't

Comment: can you help me? because on that code is a timer and i cant stop it whenever i call the onStoper() on the button, or are there any possibilities to stop that looped timer when a button is clicked?

Comment: Class names should always start with uppercase letters. :)

Comment: @Mary: Declare `TimerTask task` outside method then use `refresher.task` and also follow java naming conventions for class names,variables

Comment: so if i change it to uppercase will it fix my problem? i can call now that 'task' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible fix, is to use a dedicated method for the task cancellation:

```
public class Refre
{
    final Timer timers = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    private TimerTask task;

    public void trig(){
        task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        new activityIns().execute();
                    }
                });
            }
        };       

        timers.schedule(task, 1000, 10000);
    }

    public void cancelTask() {
        timers.cancel(); // assuming http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
    }
}
```

then:

```
private Refre refresher = new Refre();
void onStoper(){
    refresher.cancelTask();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: sir how can i stop it? when i call the `onStop` on the button it is still not stoping.. it is still looping for every 10seconds

Comment: Without seeing the full code, it's hard to tell. Also note that your question was how to access `task`, that's it. Maybe you should ask a new question with your full code (xml + activity) and ask "why the task is not stopping" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is a **local** variable. That means you can not use anywhere outside the block you are in.

To solve your problem, you can obviously save the TimerTask in a public or private variable in your `refre` class. (When you make it private make sure to create a getter as well.)

In your case, however, I assume you can easily return the TimerTask from `onTrig()` to use it in `onStopped()`.

I hope this helps!

PS: You should follow Java conventions when writing code and sharing it. These conventions describe that class names shall always start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. `task` is declared within `trig()` method, so it is accessible only within this method's scope. It is called **local variable** Take a moment to learn more about scopes, to access `task` it should be declared at least within class with public modifier (also note that it is a bad practice, you should make it private and use getters to access any of the variables within class).

BTW, when describing class name you should use first capital letter. Take a look at Java Code Conventions: [Code Conventions at Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)